# React native how to force reload the app or the root view

Tags: ios, react-native

We're building a production react native application but listview memory issues are preventing us from releasing it. Is there a way to force reload the whole app using TimerMixin or onPushReceived? We're using TabbarIOS and Navigator, if those can be taken advantage of to release all views from listview by reloading the whole app. Thank you.

Comment: it is impossible to reload an iOS app

Comment: Is it possible to reload the root view or individual components of tabbar?

Comment: Try recreate the item viewcontroller of the specific tabbar and reset the ViewControllers?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can `this.forceUpdate()` within the component

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily solution for us: Set listview to empty array then re-fetch data upon
1. AppState change to 'background' with timer for 10 minutes
2. Receiving push while AppState is 'background'